# How to improve SEO with getServerSideProps() in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, seo, server-side-rendering

I have a website that will show dynamic data (Articles), i.e data that changes hourly.

I therefore have opted to use `getServerSideProps()` from NextJS.

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const url = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL

    const articles = await fetch(url + 'article').then(res => res.json()).catch(err => console.error(err))

    console.log("articles", articles);

    return {
        props: {
            articles,
        }
    }
}
```

I could not use `getStaticPaths()` because the data changes so frequently, an hour after building the site and all the static paths would point to out-of-date articles, and all the new articles would not have any paths pointing to them. I also looked at `ISR` however this also wouldn't work as it relies on knowing the paths in advance.

My issue arises that because `getServerSideProps()` is completely dynamic, search engines do not see any of the dynamic pages (which is pretty much the entire site), and therefore I do not rank well.

Is there a way to use `getServerSideProps()` with some kind of caching, that will allow search engines to see the pages? If not, is there an alternative framework I can use that allows dynamic pages while retaining some SEO performance?

Comment: How dynamic exactly are those pages? Is their full content changing hourly? Providing a [sitemap](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) with the right `lastmod` and `changefreq` values should be enough in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, reduce the number of dynamic pages. too many dynamic pages will put your app at risk of `cloaking` and google hates it.

Generate sitemap. sitemap will improve the SEO but it is very hard for `getServerSideProps` because those functions are not available during build time. Use this npm package:  [next-sitemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-sitemap). it helps for dynamic pages too.

> Server side index-sitemaps (getServerSideSitemapIndex)
> Here's a sample script to generate index-sitemap on server side.Create pages/server-sitemap-index.xml/index.tsx page and add the following content.

```
// pages/server-sitemap-index.xml/index.tsx
import { getServerSideSitemapIndex } from 'next-sitemap'
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next'

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  // Method to source urls from cms
  // const urls = await fetch('https//example.com/api')

  return getServerSideSitemapIndex(ctx, [
    'https://example.com/path-1.xml',
    'https://example.com/path-2.xml',
  ])
}

// Default export to prevent next.js errors
export default function SitemapIndex() {}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
To enable sitemaps in Next.js, utilize the **getServerSideProps** function as explained in the official documentation, which also highlights its **SEO** and indexing benefits.

Refer to the official Next.js Sitemap **Documentation** here :- **https://nextjs.org/learn/seo/crawling-and-indexing/xml-sitemaps** for detailed instructions. Follow the steps precisely for setting up sitemaps in your Next.js application. If you encounter issues or have questions, feel free to seek assistance in this forum.

const EXTERNAL_DATA_URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

function generateSiteMap(posts) {
  return `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
     <!--We manually set the two URLs we know already-->
     <url>
       <loc>https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com</loc>
     </url>
     <url>
       <loc>https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide</loc>
     </url>
     ${posts
       .map(({ id }) => {
         return `
       <url>
           <loc>${`${EXTERNAL_DATA_URL}/${id}`}</loc>
       </url>
     `;
       })
       .join('')}
   </urlset>
 `;
}

function SiteMap() {
  // getServerSideProps will do the heavy lifting
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ res }) {
  // We make an API call to gather the URLs for our site
  const request = await fetch(EXTERNAL_DATA_URL);
  const posts = await request.json();

  // We generate the XML sitemap with the posts data
  const sitemap = generateSiteMap(posts);

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  // we send the XML to the browser
  res.write(sitemap);
  res.end();

  return {
    props: {},
  };
}

export default SiteMap;
```

Comment: Mayani Sumit, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)